# Unity - Image change color not applying in scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I simply want to create a Tabbed-Page. To do so I used a button for each tab button and I show a specific page on click. But I need the button to keep the selected color until another TabButton of the same list is selected, which is not done by default. So I tried to edit the `.colorBlock` property but the changes were only applied in the inspector but not in the scene. So I removed the button component and tried to manipulate the `Image.color` but same result. So I created my own `UI/Default - Material` and tried to change the color `Tint` of the material. But when doing this all the UI gets invisible forever as soon as I set the color and I have to restart Unity. Am I doing something wrong or is Unity completely bugged?

**Change ColorBlock:**

```
private void UpdateColor(TabButton button, Color color) {
    ColorBlock colorBlock = button.Button.colors;
    colorBlock.normalColor = color;
    colorBlock.highlightedColor = color;
    button.Button.colors = colorBlock;
}
```

**Change Image Color:**

```
private void UpdateColor(TabButton button, Color color) {
    button.Image.color = color;
}
```

**Change Material Color:**

```
private void UpdateColor(TabButton button, Color color) {
    button.Image.material.SetColor("_Color", color);
}
```

Comment: I believe the `ColorBlock` is an ongoing bug with any objects childed to a `Canvas` component. As for the other two, I would expect a `.material` call to create an instance of the material. As that does not appear to be happening, you can instance the material in either `Start` or `Awake` by doing `button.Image.material = new Material(button.Image.material)`, then just setting the color `button.Image.material.SetColor("_Color", color)` or similarly using `button.Image.color = color` as that will use the shader `_Color` by default.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with UI tabs, I always aim to write my own logic so that I can fully control what happens.

**TabsController.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class TabsController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private TabButton[] _tabButtons;

    public UnityAction<int> TabIdChangedAction;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        TabIdChangedAction += OnTabIdChanged;
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        TabIdChangedAction -= OnTabIdChanged;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        // add listener for each tab button with
        // its tab id from the array
        for (int i = 0; i < _tabButtons.Length; i++)
        {
            int id = i;

            _tabButtons[id].TButton.onClick.AddListener(() =>
            {
                ChangedCurrentTab(id);
            });
        }

        // set first tab as current
        ChangedCurrentTab(0);
    }

    public void ChangedCurrentTab(int id)
    {
        TabIdChangedAction?.Invoke(id);
    }

    // update tab buttons visuals
    // on tab id changed
    // while passing to each tab button if it's the current
    private void OnTabIdChanged(int tabId)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _tabButtons.Length; i++)
        {
            _tabButtons[i].UpdateVisuals(i == tabId);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**TabButton.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TabButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Button _tabButton;

    public Button TButton => _tabButton;

    public void UpdateVisuals(bool isCurrent)
    {
        _tabButton.image.color = isCurrent ? Color.green : Color.white;
    }
}
```

---

**Execution Overview**

https://gfycat.com/flimsydangerousairedale

---

**Note:**
This is a raw implementation just to get along with the idea.